# ASHX image handler lets document.ready() fire twice

Tags: asp.net, jquery, internet-explorer

I got a $(document).ready() handler in my aspx page that fires twice. I trapped it to the follwing line of html (this line is part of the itemtemplate of a listview):

```
<img src='Images.ashx?Url=<%# Eval("Url")%>&amp;Type=3' alt=''></img>
```

Seems that using the images.ashx is causing my problem, putting a 'normal' url as src gives me no problems.

Anybody any idea? It must be because the handler is called, but why is loading an image giving a second fire on $(document).ready()

It is only in IE8. Chrome, FF and safari work as expected.

regards,
Henk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After letting it a few days to rest I dove in it again. Turns out that when I went back from jQuery 1.4.3 to 1.4.2 the problem disappeared....

Edit few days later:

Just tried the new jQuery release (1.4.4) and this problem seems to be fixed :)